Property of Binomial Distribution
I'm having trouble identifying which property of binomial distribution allows the following equality to hold:
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \binom{n}{n-k+1} p^k (1-p)^{n-k+1} = p(1 + np -(n+1)p^n)$
where:

$n$ is the total number of trials.
$k$ represents the number of successes (ranging from 1 to $n$).
$p^k$ represents the probability of $k$ successes.
$(1-p)^{n-k+1}$ represents the probability of $n-k+1$ failures.

I can numerically validate the formula for different values of $n$, but I am unable to explain why it holds.

Hint: Recall that $ \frac{n}{k} { n - 1 \choose k - 1 } = { n \choose k }$ and $ { n \choose k } = { n \choose k -1  }$.

The sum is a manipulation of the Binomial theorem. It can be achieved via the following calculations:
$$\begin{gather*}
(t+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}t^{n-k}y^k,  \tag{1}\\ 
\int_{0}^{x} (t+y)^n dt = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\left(\int_{0}^{x} t^{n-k} dt\right)y^k, \tag{2}\\
\frac{(x+y)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{y^{n+1}}{n+1} =  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{n-k+1}\binom{n}{k} x^{n-k+1} y^k, \\
(x+y)^n - y^n =  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{n-k+1}\binom{n}{k} x^{n-k+1} y^{k-1}, \tag{3}\\
(x+y)^ny - y^{n+1} =  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{n-k+1}\binom{n}{k} x^{n-k+1} y^{k},  \tag{4}\\
(x+y)^n +ny(x+y)^{n-1} - (n+1)y^{n} =  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k^2}{n-k+1}\binom{n}{k} x^{n-k+1} y^{k-1},  \tag{5}
\end{gather*}$$
where we have done

Written the Binomial theorem.
Integrated over variable $t$ from $0$ to $x>0$.
Taken partial derivative with respect to $y$.
Multiplied both sides by $y$, $y\ne 0$.
Taken partial derivative with respect to $y$.

Now since $\frac{k^2}{n-k+1}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{k^2}{n-k+1}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = k\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}=k \cdot \binom{n}{n-k+1}$, we obtain, $$\boxed{ \sum_{k=0}^{n} k  \binom{n}{n-k+1} x^{n-k+1} y^{k} = y\big( (x+y)^n +ny(x+y)^{n-1} - (n+1)y^{n} \big)} $$
Now simply substitute $x=1-p$ and $y=p$ to get the required sum.

Nicely done! One more question: what will be the transition from step 2 to 3 if the variables are discrete?

You mean $x,y$ are varying only in integers?

Yes, just considering this case out of curiosity.

Well then I can't differentiate my equation. So Initially both variables $x,y$ are running over the real line.
